# Calculating BPM from an MP3 in Java

Tags: java, mp3

Is there a way to calculate the BPM of an audio file in Java? Or is this an attribute accessible from the metadata?

Comment: I would try google before you post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TrackAnalyzer is a java based command line tool that estimates the musical key
and bpm of digital recordings. As Beats per minute is not a feature of the track, this is an estimate.

You can find more information and source code here

https://github.com/tfriedel/trackanalyzer

Comment: Important to note. The library is GPL.

Comment: @h3xStream why is it a problem that it is GPL.. Don't use FOSS if you don't like sharing